# Searching YouTube with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube

I have a simple app to search YouTube. When I run it I get no errors, but nothing actually happens when I click the search button!

Below is the relevant code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            searchResults: []
        }
        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
        this.showResults = this.showResults.bind(this);
    }

    showResults(response) {
        this.setState({
            searchResults: response.results
        })
        console.log(response)
    }

    search(searchTerm) {
        fetch("www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
            type: "GET",
            part: 'snippet',
            url: "www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",
            key: "my key",
            q: searchTerm,
            success: function(response) {
                this.showResults(response);
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <div>
               <Searchbox search={this.search}/>
               <Mapresults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
           </div>
        )
    }
}

class Searchbox extends React.Component{
    createAjax(){
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';
        var key = 'AIzaSyCBPX-gonEMREh2OyT3S9Q7oaxBFaxkBZs';
        var searchresult = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.query).value;
        var fullUrl = url + key + searchresult;
        this.props.search(fullUrl);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form id="search-term">
                    <input ref="query" type="text"/><button id="search-term" onChange=
                        {() => this.createAjax.bind(this)}/>
                </form>
                <h2 id= "root">test</h2>
                <h2 id="demo"></h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried to fix it it and added react developer tools but it just doesn't seem to render.

Comment: that's not a good idea to leave your `key` here in public, replace it with `key:"my key"`

Comment: Thanks, changed :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than retrieving the value of your search box using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.query).value`, try using a [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) pattern. This allows the state of your component to drive the presentation, and not the other way around.

Here's a snippet of your Searchbox component, with the controlled component pattern implemented:

```js
class Searchbox extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchText: ''
    };
  }

  handleSearchClick = e => {
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search";
    var key = "AIzaSyCBPX-gonEMREh2OyT3S9Q7oaxBFaxkBZs";
    var searchresult = this.state.searchText;
    var fullUrl = url + key + searchresult;
    this.props.search(fullUrl);
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ searchText: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form id="search-term">
          <input
            ref="query"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.searchText}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <button
            id="search-term"
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleSearchClick}
          >
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
        <h2 id="root">test</h2>
        <h2 id="demo" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Making this change allowed me to successfully call the youtube API, although I received a `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error, which I assume you will be handling in your actual code.